# Syncing Active campaign and Superio-Job Board WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, activecampaign

The goal is to sync user data from the theme forms to Active Campaign. I am having trouble setting this up.The challenge however is to sync the user details including email, name, dob, number, address etc. which is gathered from a theme form [I can't edit the form from backend I only have shortcode - Theme support is not much of a help]

I did set up the new user sync through wordpress using zapier but it only syncs the user email and doesn't differentiate between a candidate account or an employer account. or syncs any email, name, dob, number, address etc details.